# Restricted Read Access Problems

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, master-page

Created a page granted visitors "Restricted Read" access.  For some reason anyone that only has visitors access is not able to view the page.  Is this because "Restricted Read" is selected as the permission group? To make this go away, should I create a new home page and change the permissions?

Comment: What kind of page you have created web part page, publishing or a regular page. Coming to Restricted Readers they do have access to view pages, documents but cannot be able to download that is the diff between Read and restricted read. Check if you have modified your master page and not published it , if not published publish it and check.

Comment: Or any other unpublished assets like CSS, scripts, or images.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  This the master page (default).  The page is checked in and published.  I tried creating a new page and the same issue exists.  It's also produces this message when I go to Pages To view your documents, please navigate to the library and select the 'Open with Explorer' action. If the 'Open with Explorer' action is not available, then your system may not support it."

Answer (score -2):

Can you check the version history of the page. If it does not have a major version published, publish a major version.

Thanks,
Virender